# Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\ln\left(\cos{\frac{1}{3^n}}\right)x^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I need to find the radius of convergence of
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{\ln\left(\cos{\frac{1}{3^n}}\right)x^n}$$.

I came up with the following solution:

Since $\cos{\frac{1}{3^n}\sim1-\frac{1}{2(3^n)^2}}$, then
$$\ln\left(\cos{\frac{1}{3^n}}\right)\sim\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{2(3^n)^2}\right)\sim-\frac{1}{2(3^n)^2}$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\ln\left(\cos{\frac{1}{3^n}}\right)x^n}\sim\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{-\frac{x^n}{2(3^n)^2}}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^n}{2(3^n)^2}},$$ where we can assess easily what the radius is using the ratio test:
$$R = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|.$$
Is the solution correct? If not, could you suggest an alternative solution, please?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Thank you, I have an argument with my friends, who claim that one can't use similar functions in these sequences.

Comment: You can, if you justify it

Comment: @Meowdog By justification you mean that I can use $f(x)\sim g(x)$ only if I prove that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}=1$, right?

Comment: Yes, or quote some results. But there is no problem with using similar functions

Comment: Thanks again! You were very helpful!

Comment: The root test is more direct.

Comment: @MarkViola Hey there, thanks for the feedback. At the time asking, I didn't know about root test and I still don't because it wasn't part of the course and I had no other calculus classes. It's nice to know other alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a few commentors have pointed out: Yes, this looks good. Ratio test is always going to be your friend on questions such as these. Let's go ahead and work it out so you're sure you got the right final answer:

\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} &= \frac{{\frac{x^{n+1}}{2(3^{n+1})^2}}}{{\frac{x^n}{2(3^n)^2}}}\\
&= {\frac{x^{n+1}}{2(3^{n+1})^2}}\cdot\frac{2(3^n)^2}{x^n}\\
&= {\frac{x}{(3^{n+1})^2}}\cdot\frac{(3^n)^2}{1}\\
&= {\frac{x}{3^2}}\cdot\frac{1}{1}\\
&= {\frac{x}{9}}\\
\end{align}
so we have that radius of convergence is $-9 \leqslant x \leqslant 9$.

Comment: This should be a comment, not a posted solution.

Comment: The user asked if his solution was correct, and it was. See this recent meta post: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35479/treatment-of-comment-answered-questions-what-is-the-current-policy-as-of-februa?cb=1

Comment: Following https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20097/how-to-answer-proof-verification-questions/, I think the answer in its current form should've been a comment. If you point out in the answer what you changed (and maybe also why), it could be an answer.

Comment: I just added the completion of OP's question.

Comment: Hello everyone. I guess it's my fault for this situation. My question was answered in the comments but I couldn't close it, because none of the available reasons actually matched the real reason, which is - the comments were enough of an answer. I will mark this answer as accepted, so that the question is interpreted as resolved and doesn't draw extra effort. Moreover, Clyde also provided the rest of the solution, which could be of help to someone. I apologise for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @KotakaDanski, nothing was at all your fault. We are just talking about what is customary for an answer on a question like this.

Comment: This situation actually brings up a serious topic - what to do with questions, which have been resolved in the comments. Is there an accepted behaviour in such a case, or there's no way to actually mark the question as answered? If it's the latter, I think it would be a good idea to add an option to mark the question as answered, as answering your own question in this case is a corrupt practice in my opinion - it gives you reputation, even though the comments resolved it.

Comment: I agree, which is why I asked this question on meta a few days ago: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35479/treatment-of-comment-answered-questions-what-is-the-current-policy-as-of-februa?cb=1